# Add regex to lines in text file if it isn't already present

Tags: regex, powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to add regex to the beginning of each line in a text file if it isn't already present. The input is a list of urls and the regex is a list of protocols.

I've tried different if/else loops and cmdlets like add-content/set-content to add the regex but the logic is off each time. Currently what I have is:

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\path\to\file\test.txt"
$pattern = "[regex]::^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)" 
ForEach-Object { 
    if ($content -match $pattern) 
        {$content}
    else {
        {foreach($_ in $content) {"^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)" + $_ }}
          }
 } | Out-File "C:\path\to\file\test.txt"
```

I'd like the output to be

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)netflix.com
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)google.com
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)yahoo.com
```

but the actual output is

```
"^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)" + $_
```

Comment: You’ve created a script block around your Foreach inside of your else. Remove the { before and remove the } after the Foreach.

Comment: Without a sample of your input it's difficult to deduce what your code is supposed to do. IMO your pattern could be simplified to `$pattern = [regex]"^(https?:\/\/(www\.)?|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this, but I had to guess for some things in the input.

This is what I used for input

```
google.com
yahoo.com
netflix.com
```

This is the modified powershell I used.  If a line in the input does not match have the pattern at the beginning of the line, it will replace the current string with the replacement text including the pattern.  It then looks for the index of the original string in the input and replaces it.  Finally it writes it all back to the original file.

```
$content = Get-Content "C:\path\to\file\test.txt"
$pattern = "^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)" 

$content | ForEach-Object { 
    if ($_ -notlike $pattern +"*") {
        #Write-Host "^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)" + $_ 
        $replaceText = $_ -replace "^$_$", "$pattern$_"  
        $content[($content.IndexOf("$($content -like "$_")"))] = $replaceText
    }
}

$content | Set-Content "C:\path\to\file\test.txt"
```

The output of the update file is:

```
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)google.com
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)yahoo.com
^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/|tcp:\/\/|ssl:\/\/)netflix.com
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the -replace of $replaceText id "^$_$", which is regex ^ startof line, $_ from the pipe and regext $ end of line.

Comment: That does exactly what I had in mind! Thanks so much! You were correct with the inputs, I apologize for not making that clear in the original post. The original list has over 12,000 entries on it so i was trying to keep it simple for testing purposes. 
 If some entries on the list already have a protocol in the beginning of the line (http:// netflix.com) this script will just add the regex pattern to the front of that. Is it possible to replace that protocol with the regex pattern?

Comment: Figured it out. I added     ```$content = $content -replace "http://","" ```     and that solves the problem.